# Azure ADF: Can I manually set (or in some other way force) the final "Status" of a pipeline to be "Succeeded?

Tags: status, azure-data-factory

As far as I can tell, a pipeline "Fails" if *any* of the Activities fail.

That makes it very easy to deliberately fail an otherwise succeeding Pipeline; just conditionally execute a bogus Web Activity :D

But what about the opposite?

Suppose one of my Activities has "Failed" in a way that I not a problem, and which I have accounted for in my conditional flows. The fallback path has executed smoothly, and no further intervention is required. The pipeline finishes, but it gets marked as "Failed" :(

Is there anything I can do to "override" the Failure from the intermediary Activity, and force the overall Pipeline to report a success?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to force the overall Pipeline to report a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that the condition for a pipeline to fail is:

- Either:

  - An activity fails, with no "on Failure" dependency.
- Or:

  - At least one activity has been skipped as a direct result of a dependency on the activity failing.

The "direct" in the 2nd clause is non-trivial. For example if C depends on B being skipped, and B depends on A failing, then if A fails, that's the *in*direct cause of C not running, but it doesn't error overall.

Which means that depending on the structure of your piepline, you can *probably* suppress the error? I think? But it might be *really* ugly!

Further research required :D

Answer (score 0):

Just a pile on to @Brondahls answer, the documentation is oddly worded, but it seems if you bind any of the subsequent steps to a skip step that succeeds then its fine.

I have a final operator in my pipeline that all the skips are set to which populates a meaningless value, when my procedure "fails" and finds something running, the pipeline still succeeds.

[image: A basic pipeline in Data Factory with all outputs having a skip pointing to a single set variable operator SeeIfADFIsGarbage]

Comment: Just an update on this, tested it and successfully deployed but after several days ADF started throwing a tizz and added additional output mappings... Very odd. I contacted MSFT and they couldn't puzzle it out so I poked at reconfiguring and while I can get the pipeline to run the errors still persist :)

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possiable.

**As long as one part causes an error, the pipeline will failed.**

Your idea cannot be realized.

Comment: `As long as one part causes an error, the pipeline will failed.` This (as stated) is incorrect. I have a pipeline which overall passes, despite some activities failing.
Do not (as yet) understand *why* that's the case, though :D It's entirely possible that what I want can't be achieved, but it's not as simple as this answer implies.

Comment: see my current answer. If you can find a case that isn't explained by those rules I'd be keen to know about it - extra data can only improve my model :D